# Are the poll results likely to be valid if they are based on only those subjects who agree to respond?

Tags: statistics

I found this question in the book "Essentials of Statistics" written by Mario Triola.

When Gallup and other polling organizations conduct polls, they typically contact subjects by telephone. In recent years, many subjects refuse to cooperate with the poll.

Are the poll results likely to be valid if they are based on only those subjects who agree to respond? What should do polling organizations do when they encounter a subject who refuses to respond?

If I were doing the poll, I would replace the subjects that did not accept to answer with new randomly selected subjects.

Would that be correct?

This is not a homework.

Comment: This question might be better suited for stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: I did not know that stats.stackexchange.com exists. Thanks!

Comment: By doing that, you only would erase/blur the only piece of information you have. Of course, there might be the bias you describe but what you propose is not a solution at all.

Comment: What would be your solution?

Comment: @Beginner There is not a mathematical answer; I believe that the incentive approach described by Morawitz is better. Or some other trick. I heard about a survey that tried to estimate which newspaper people read; of course, comming to a house and asking would result in bias. They pretended that they are collecting old trash-papers and then nobody had problem to give them bunches of old newspapers.. At least the bias is not so obvious then.

Comment: Brilliant strategy Peter! But how could you do that with an opinion poll? If you were in charge what would you do?

Comment: It should be mentioned that this whole discussion has its own specific field of study associated with it: Survey Methodology (a subcategory of applied statistics) with several good textbooks [such as this one](http://www.amazon.com/International-Handbook-Methodology-European-Association/dp/0805857532/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1419045874&sr=1-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider an election for state governor between a conservative candidate and a progressive candidate where 90% of the people in the state would vote conservative but the issues didn't interest them very much and only 5% of conservatives would actually go to the polls on election day.  In other words, $90\%\cdot5\%=4.5\%$ of the total state population actually go out to vote conservative.

The progressive candidate on the other hand riled up the progressive voters and got a whopping 80% voter turnout among progressives on election day because there was a big issue they wanted changed.  In other words, $10\%\cdot 80\% = 8\%$ of the state population came to the election to vote for the progressive candidate.

In this case, as there were more votes cast for the progressive candidate (8 votes for progressive for every 4.5 votes for conservative), he wins the election despite there being a much larger conservative population.

The election results show that 64% of the people who voted supported the progressive candidate and only 36% supported the conservative candidate.  Trying to use this to describe the entire state however does not produce accurate results as we know 90% of the people in fact support the conservative candidate.

In much the same way, phone based polling companies get information from only those people who choose to answer the phone.  It may well be that the ones who answer the phone have very strong opinions, and those who have a different opinion are more likely not to answer the phone, despite being more numerous.  All we can say is for certain is what those who responded to the poll said.  While it could hopefully be extended to describe the entire population, that is not necessarily the case.

The biggest issue I see here is that voter response is voluntary and is not guaranteed to be the same between different groups.  Not much can be done to remedy the situation except by trying to reduce the chance that someone refuses to be polled.

A common practice is that they offer some sort of incentive to participate in the polling process.  Many restaurants and businesses offer small free services or entry into a lottery drawing if you participate in a survey.  In doing so, they hope that the promise of some incentive will have all opinions voiced and not just those of a specific group.

This practice has been documented as having been in use since the early 1800's.  Various studies attempt to answer the question of the efficacy of using incentives for data collection such as this [research article](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2288/11/81) by Joan Griffin and this [research article](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2600442/) by Singer and Couper.

---

One of the biggest things to remember again, is that voicing an opinion is entirely voluntary, and many times only occurs to us as being something that we should do when something angers or upsets us.  Take the "Hows My Driving" bumper stickers on the end of a company truck for example.  I'd wager that they almost always receive only phonecalls by people with road rage upset about something, yet I've never encountered a problem with them personally and have seen hundreds of them on the road.  **I challenge anyone reading this** to give them a call next time and thank them for driving safely and respectfully (assuming it was true) to give them something nice to hear for a change and to thank other people around you that you haven't thought to thank before.

Comment: Would not be wrong to give that kind of incentives because you would have a voluntary response, and that was the mistake that polls had at the beginning of the previous century?

Comment: The biggest point to make I suppose, is to always take quoted statistics with a grain of salt.  Realize that regardless what precautionary measures, the results may still be skewed in one way or another, either due to specific sample population or the method of recording statistics.  http://xkcd.com/1453/

Comment: In my perspective, incentives are good to get feedback from customers but not for statistics.

Comment: It is common practice for many fields and professions to use incentives and monetary compensation for data.  Take the medical research field for example.  They pay people to test meds and new procedures (or at least provide free care).  In most every case nowadays where participation is voluntary and not mandatory you will see some benefit for the voter/tester/surveyed.

Comment: There was a time when having Gallup call you up and ask your opinion was a novelty, and people were happy to participate.  Now it's just an annoyance.  Why should I provide valuable data to a commercial enterprise for free?

Comment: What Robert says it is true, but... what would you do if you are in charge of the poll?

Comment: In my perspective what Moravitz says about the incentives, works for some kinds of experiments, but does not work for observational studies.

Comment: To explore the question further might cross into the realm of Sociology and other Social Sciences to figure out why people act in certain ways.  From a mathematical perspective we can identify potential problems which give observational bias to our experiments and skew our data.  In the case of the phone poller, one of the biggest unknown variables is whether the other person agrees to be polled (others problems include things like honesty).  Having identified a problem doesn't mean we can always create a perfect solution to it, but we can hopefully lessen it's effects on the experiment.

Comment: Your idea to hire social scientists sounds really interesting!  But, in the meantime, we need to find a faster solution. I see few options: 
a) Repeat the experiment. But it will be expensive plus the fact that we can have again the same problem.
b) Use the other results.
c) Replace the subjects that did not answer the opinion poll with other randomly selected subjects.
I vote for the last option.
I would love to know what Gallup does.

Comment: I think maybe you misinterpreted what I meant.  I had not yet discussed what to do in the situation that you are a poller with unresponsive subjects and just discussed how to approach the issue before ever beginning an experiment and hoping to alleviate it during the setup.  If in your case, without changing how you conduct the poll in all of your listed options you will have the same potential issue of a specific target group being nonresponsive.  What most would do is ignore it and hope for the best.  As always though, more data is better, so I would probably agree with c with some prizes.